# Error: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0) while extracting a map from file with json_serde

Tags: rust, serde-json

To check how to use serde_json::to_writer() and serde_json::from_reader() I use a very simple main(), no problem when I just write but a strange error when I add the reader
Error: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)

I just start to learn rust ...

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string());
    map.insert("hello".to_string(), "you".to_string());
    map.insert("to".to_string(), "you".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", map);

    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("foo_serde.json")?;
    // why does this work?

    serde_json::to_writer(&file, &map)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let output: HashMap<String, String> = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;
    println!("{:?}", output);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This code example does not work out-of-the-box: you're missing `create(true)` in `OpenOptions`. Otherwise, it expects the file to already exist.

```rust
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("foo_serde.json")?;
```

2. You are getting an "end-of-file" error, because files have a "cursor" that indicates what position to read or write at, and after writing, this cursor is at the end of the file. This can be observed by importing `std::io::Seek`, and executing:

```rust
    dbg!(file.stream_position().unwrap());
```

after you write to the file. The output is: `[src/main.rs:22] file.stream_position().unwrap() = 38`.

serde understandably fails, as it expects content, but there's nothing left to read past position 38.

To fix this, rewind the file to the start before creating `BufReader` and passing it to serde:

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader, Seek, SeekFrom};
// ...
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // ...
    serde_json::to_writer(&file, &map)?;
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    // ...
}
```